# How can I change text content every day with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I am making sort of a script to show different content everyday with a different image and title. I already got the image loop to show every day a different picture but I need help to do the same with the title.

It is for making like a dynamic page of a discount deals which is different every day but repeats itself after one week so I only need to have 7 pictures and 7 titles to show.

Here is my code for only the loop of the images every day.

```
var dailyPhotos;
var today, img;
    dailyPhotos = function() {
     today = new Date();
     weekday = today.getDay();
     showImages = [ ];
     myPhotos = [ "{{root}}assets/img/sunday.jpg", "{{root}}assets/img/monday.jpg", "{{root}}assets/img/tuesday.jpg", "{{root}}assets/img/wednesday.jpg", "{{root}}assets/img/thirsday.png", "{{root}}assets/img/friday.jpg", "{{root}}assets/img/saterday.jpg" ]; // You must specify the path or file name of your images that will be loaded in a weekday basis.
      if ( document.images ) {
         for ( var x = 0; x < myPhotos.length; x++ ) {
         showImages[ x ] = new Image();
         showImages[ x ].src = myPhotos[ x ];
       } img = (( document.getElementById ) ? document.getElementById("yourImageId") : document.images.yourImageId ); // Specify the id of the image that will get raplaced daily.
          img.src = showImages[ weekday ].src;
          img.alt = myPhotos[ weekday ];
     } return false; // If the browser can't display images, then EXIT FUNCTION.
    };
window.onload = dailyPhotos;
```

and this is how i want to display it in html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="column large-6 medium-6 small-12">
            <h4> THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE TITLE TO BE DISPLAYED </h4>
            <p> IF I CAN DISPLAY P TEKST WITH IT I WOULD HAVE IT IN HERE </p>
            <a href="More details medium-6 small-12"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="column large-6"><img id="yourImageId" src="tuesdayPhoto.jpg" alt="DEMO" /> THIS IS WHERE THE IMAGE IS DISPLAYED </div>
    </div>
```

I know it can be done with javascript, thanks for trying to help if you are reading this.

```js
var dailyPhotos;
var today, img;
    dailyPhotos = function() {
     today = new Date();
     weekday = today.getDay();
     showImages = [ ];
     myPhotos = [ "{{root}}assets/img/sunday.jpg", "{{root}}assets/img/monday.jpg", "{{root}}assets/img/tuesday.jpg", "{{root}}assets/img/wednesday.jpg", "http://s.cdpn.io/37045/wedding-1.jpg", "{{root}}assets/img/friday.jpg", "{{root}}assets/img/saterday.jpg" ]; // You must specify the path or file name of your images that will be loaded in a weekday basis.
      if ( document.images ) {
         for ( var x = 0; x < myPhotos.length; x++ ) {
         showImages[ x ] = new Image();
         showImages[ x ].src = myPhotos[ x ];
       } img = (( document.getElementById ) ? document.getElementById("yourImageId") : document.images.yourImageId ); // Specify the id of the image that will get raplaced daily.
          img.src = showImages[ weekday ].src;
          img.alt = myPhotos[ weekday ];
     } return false; // If the browser can't display images, then EXIT FUNCTION.
    };
window.onload = dailyPhotos;
```

```html
<div class="row"> <div class="column large-6 medium-6 small-12"> <h4> THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE TITLE TO BE DISPLAYED </h4> <p> IF I CAN DISPLAY P TEKST WITH IT I WOULD HAVE IT IN HERE </p> <a href="More details medium-6 small-12"></a> </div> <div class="column large-6"> <img id="yourImageId" src="tuesdayPhoto.jpg" alt="DEMO" /> THIS IS WHERE THE IMAGE IS DISPLAhttp://stackoverflow.com/posts/43251456/edit#YED </div> </div>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and use lorempixel to create a [mcve]

Comment: did it, but you dont see the image

Comment: https://dummyimage.com/300&text=Monday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go!

https://jsfiddle.net/bja94uLz/1/

First get the date

```
var d = new Date();
```

Then get the day

```
var n = d.getDay();
```

Then you can make an array with your titles. Doesn't need to be below the above

```
var titles = ['title 1', 'title 2', 'title 3', 'title 4', 'title 5', 'title 6', 'title 7'];
```

And then just change the title by replacing the content in the div with id title

```
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = titles[n-1];
```

It's 'n-1' because arrays start at 0

You can actually get away with using 1 less variable.
https://jsfiddle.net/bja94uLz/2/

Comment: thanksssssss it worksss i wil give you cred after 2 minutes then i can pick an answer

Comment: Pleassssssure :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
text = ((document.getElementById) ? document.getElementById("text"): document.images.yourImageId);
text.innerHTML = myText[weekday];
```

---

```
<div id="text"></div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/LcxLy421/